# How to know how many resources a process uses in all its execution time? linux

Tags: linux

I would like to know if there is a program to analyze how many resources it takes to execute a command.
for example as follows:

```
# magic_program python3 app.py
```

And that the program tells you how many resources the execution of a program uses, the use of cpu, memory, disk, network, etc.

that in a certain way watches over the program during execution and then gives you a report. If it doesn't exist, I would love to carry out a project like this.

#### Questions

Is there this magic program? if not, how viable would its creation be?

Comment: Perhaps `man 1 time` will give you something to start with.

Comment: BTW, your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Thanks, I will do it